# Steady State Markov Chain

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

I was reading http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/mbk-58-prev.pdf and going through the first example for the frog jumping between the lily pads. I'm interested in find the steady-state probability for the fraction of time that the frog spends in the east lily pad.

Basically, given the transition matrix: 
$P = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1-p & p\\
q & 1-q\\
\end{array}
\right]$

I want to find $\pi = \pi P$.

They get $\pi(e) = \frac{q}{q+p}$, which makes intuitive sense.  However, no matter what I try I can't get a solution in terms of $p$ and $q$. They keep dropping out.

For example, I can view the formula above as an eigenvalue problem with $\lambda=1$, but the eigenvector I get is $(1,1)$ making $\pi(e)=1/2$.

This definitely satisfies $\pi(e) = \frac{q}{q+p}$ if $p=q=1/2$, but it's not a general solution.

I've seen this problem done before involving a geometric distribution, but I'm not entirely sure why the linear algebra approach is failing for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you calculate the left eigenvector and not the right egienvector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you calculate the correct eigenvector:
$$\pi(P-I) = \pi\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
-p & p\\
q & -q\\
\end{array}
\right]=0$$
$$\implies \pi=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{q}{p+q} & \frac{p}{p+q}
\end{array}
\right]$$

Comment: Thanks! I ended up row reducing to $\pi_1-(p/q)\pi_2=0$ and then solving that with $\pi_1+\pi_2=1$ - is there a better way?

Comment: aside from just row-reducing with the additional equation from the getgo

Comment: I just used inspection to get $(q,p)$ and then divided by $p+q$ to make the sum of the elements 1. However, if you want to use row-reduction take the transpose of the $P-I$ then perform the normal row operations.