# Cloudy and Sunny Days

Tags: conditional-probability

In Freedonia, every day is either cloudy or sunny (not both). If it's sunny on any given day, then the probability that the next day will be sunny is $\frac 34$. If it's cloudy on any given day, then the probability that the next day will be cloudy is $\frac 23$.

In the long run, what fraction of days are sunny?

How am I to solve this? My initial thought of 9/17 (obtained by $\frac{\frac{3}{4}}{\frac{3}{4}+\frac{2}{3}}$) was incorrect.

Comment: A similar problem  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512674/steady-state-markov-chain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a two-state transient Markov chain.  The transition matrix is
$$P = \left[\matrix{3/4 & 1/4\cr 1/3 & 2/3}\right] $$
Can you find a fixed probability vector for this matrix?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what that means. I'm not _that_ good at math. What's a Markov chain?

Answer (score 1):

Use the law of total probability:

$$P(S)=P(S_2\mid S_1)P(S)+ (1-P(C_1 \mid C_2))(1-P(S))$$
where $P(S)$ is the probability of a sunny day, $P(S_2|S_1)$ is the probability of a sunny day following a sunny day and $P(C_2|C_1)$ is the probability of a cloudy day following a cloudy day.

\begin{gather}
P(S)=3P(S)/4+ (1-2/3)(1-P(S))\\
P(S)/4=1/3 -P(S)/3\\
7P(S)/12=1/3\\
P(S)=4/7\\
\end{gather}